# How to get values from another view and use it in same activity?

Tags: java, android

Hi I want to write a simple application for calculating the area of a triangle and I want the user to set the height and base of the triangle in `Edittext` view and by clicking on a `button` it shows the result in the `Edittext` view down below but my application crashes.
this is my  code :
[java code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xpR1U.png)

[java code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xpR1U.png)

```
public class Activity2 extends AppCompatActivity {
TextView txtmasahat;
EditText edttext_ghaede;
EditText edttext_ertefa;
Button btnmosalas;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_2);
    txtmasahat=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtmasahat) ;
    btnmosalas=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnmosalas);
    edttext_ertefa=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.edttext_ertefa);
    edttext_ghaede=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.edttext_ghaede);

    btnmosalas.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            int input1=edttext_ghaede.getInputType();
            int input2=edttext_ertefa.getInputType();
            double masahat=input1*input2/2;






        }
    });
```

Comment: `getInputType` reference to `inputType` property, not to text. Use `getText().toString()` to get string from EditText, and cast it to int. I suggest you to read tutorial for begginers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 edttext_ertefa=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.edttext_ertefa);
    edttext_ghaede=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.edttext_ghaede);

    btnmosalas.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            int input1=Integer.parseInt(edttext_ghaede.getText().toString().trim());
            int input2=Integer.parseInt(edttext_ertefa..getText().toString().trim());
            double masahat= input1 * input2/2;
        }
    });
```

Also set this to your xml inside  ....

```
android:inputType="number"
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this code will helps you.

```
  btnmosalas.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            String input1=edttext_ghaede.getText().toString();
            String input2=edttext_ertefa.getText().toString();

            if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(input1)&&!TextUtils.isEmpty(input2))
           {
            Integer 

                  Integer      masahat=Integer.parseInt(input1)*Integer.parseInt(input2)/2;
            }

    });
```

Answer (score 1):

.getInputType() does not return the int value you expect. You can use the following code instead

```
public class Activity2 extends AppCompatActivity {
TextView txtmasahat;
EditText edttext_ghaede;
EditText edttext_ertefa;
Button btnmosalas;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_2);
    txtmasahat=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtmasahat) ;
    btnmosalas=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnmosalas);
    edttext_ertefa=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.edttext_ertefa);
    edttext_ghaede=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.edttext_ghaede);

    btnmosalas.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            String input1Str=edttext_ghaede.getText().toString();
            String input2Str=edttext_ertefa.getText().toString();
            int input1 = Integer.parseInt(input1Str);
            int input2 = Integer.parseInt(input2Str);
            double masahat=input1*input2/2;






        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

```
int input1=edttext_ghaede.getInputType();
```

What you need isn't `getInputType()`. You need to use `getText().toString()` to retrieve data from that `EditText'.

Also, you'll need to convert the `String` you get into an `Integer`. For that, the complete statement will become:

```
Integer.parseInt(edttext_ghaede.getText().toString());
```

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

```
 int input1=Integer.parseInt(edttext_ghaede.getText().toString());
```

Comment: It does not fix the problem.

Comment: sorry check it again

Comment: However, the correct method is `getText().toString()`

Comment: please accpet my answer if it helped u

Comment: I did not answer.

Answer (score 0):

Get a value from edittext using

```
int input1=Integer.parseInt(eedttext_ertefa.getText().toString());
```

instead of

```
 int input1=edttext_ghaede.getInputType();
```

> InputType is use for what we ristrict to user to enter text/number
>   like below code set inputtype number.

```
editText.setInputType(EditorInfo.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);
```